# Is there way to set the real maximal output sound level in Ubuntu?

Tags: sound

Different audio sources, different output devices, it's all produce different sound levels, which may be not nice at times.
Is it possible to put some kind of normalizer atop all of this?

Comment: What Ubuntu version?

Comment: @David 20.04.1.